# Prevent users on Dropbox for Business from changing their password; allow creating private folders

Tags: dropbox

We are planning to buy Dropbox for Business and want to know if it's possible to prevent users from being able to change their password.

Additionally, they should be allowed to create their own private folders despite sharing a Dropbox user account. Can this be done?